# Download updates from peer computer over LAN

Tags: linux, windows, upgrade, internet, lan

As you may have heard, Microsoft announced that Windows 10 will allow you to download updates not just from their servers, but from multiple sources using peer-to-peer over LAN and the Internet.

My question is: Is there such feature that exists for Linux?

source: http://wccftech.com/windows-10-lets-updates-torrents/

Comment: Well, this will most likely depend on the Linux distribution in question and its package management system. While it is conceivable, I'm not aware of a distribution using this approach.

Comment: Fedora allows you to set up a local mirror also,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge no distro uses peer-to-peer for downloading packages. If you have lots of computers running the same Linux distribution most package management systems allow you to run your own repositories and mirrors. This is useful if you have a slow internet connection or if you have a very large amount of machines running the same distribution.

I did a quick google search for this, however, and I found [apt-p2p](http://www.camrdale.org/apt-p2p/). This looks like a peer-to-peer solution for Debian (and possibly Debian derivatives like Ubuntu) repositories. I have never tried this, but it might be worth looking into.

Edit: I also found [p2pacman](https://github.com/onny/p2pacman) for Arch Linux, this piece of software seems to be more of an experiment than something ready for wide usage.

Answer (score -1):

**Try any other answers first**

You could just set up a server that mirrors the main Ubuntu download server [maybe with `apt-mirror` - haven't tried this] and modify your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to download from the local server.